# Prebuilt Azure Devops Boards

Tags: azure-devops

Im happy with the Kanban side of Devops along with dashboards etc.  The team is looking to try to roll out multiple projects, but all with the same Epics, Features, Backlog and Tasks etc etc ie a repeatable project.  Although im fairly sure the answer is no, is there a way to build out a project with all the work items, and then copy this as a file, and when creating a new one, use this as the basis??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is there a way to build out a project with all the work items, and then copy this as a file, and when creating a new one, use this as the basis??

When you create new projects, you can use the same Process.

For copy the work items as the basis, I suggest that you can export Work items to excel , then when you can import the exported work items to new projects.

For more detailed info, you can refer to this doc: [Bulk import or update work items using CSV files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/import-work-items-from-csv?view=azure-devops)

Comment: Ah good idea, hadnt thought of just doing it that way and keeping an Exel file safe somewhere to act as the template for each new project.  Thank you :)